# What is the maximum number of FC switches in a switched star-topology fabric with a 4-domain fabric license on the hub switch?

Tags: storage-area-network, fibre-channel, brocade

I have 2 blade chassis, with 2 built-in fibre-channel switches each.

And I inherited a "budget" fibre-channel switch with a 4-domain fabric license.

I need a reality check, please:

When I connect each of the 4 built-in switches with an ISL to the "budget" switch, that would create a fabric with 5 switches. Then I would assume that the fabric will only allow 4 switches (i.e., domains) on the fabric, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like Brocade. If it is, a "4 domain" license will allow four switches (anything with a "Domain ID" setting) in the fabric. So yes, you are correct.

Comment: yes, it's a re-branded Brocade. Gotta love those schemes were they separate sales features from tech features.